# Cannot find database created with Entity Framework 6.1.3 in SSMS

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, visual-studio-2015, entity-framework-6

The short question is... Where's my database?

I am trying to view it (and interact with it) in SSMS and cannot seem to find it.

Secondary question... Where are the *.mdf and *.ldf files?  I would have expected them somewhere in this hierarchy "C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Local DB\Instances"

The web application runs as expected.  The seeded data is in the app. So I know the Db was created somewhere.

Here is my connectionString from the web.config:

```
connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=SmartSupport2;Integrated Security=True;"
```

This is what my context says it's connecting to:

[image]

This is what SQL Server shows:

[image]

And finally, this is what SQL Server Object Explorer (VS 2015) shows:

[image]

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Is there a `.mdb` file in your project [directory] somewhere?

Comment: Usually `(localdb)` denotes a SQL Server LocalDB instance rather than a running SQL Server instance, and this usually puts an MDB file in your project.  Try replacing `(localdb)` with `localhost` instead and see what happens.

Comment: I don't think that is entirely accurate.  SQL Express (localDb) does indeed create *.mdf files. [See here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlexpress/2011/10/28/localdb-where-is-my-database/)  Regardless, I tried the change as suggested and received a "could not find server" error

Comment: Did you check this out: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlexpress/2011/10/28/localdb-where-is-my-database/

Comment: I did... I actually referenced the same link in my comment above.  Thanks though.